# Java Spring | get Pojo class content in handleMethodArgumentNotValid method

Tags: java, spring

I want request body's pojo class in handleMethodArgumentNotValid() at GlobalExceptionHandler class

my controller is

```java
@RestController
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/createUser", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponsePacket createUser(HttpServletRequest request, @Valid @RequestBody RequestPacket requestPacket) {
        ResponsePacket resp = new ResponsePacket();
        return resp;
    }
}
```

My request packet pojo class is

```java
public class RequestPacket {

    @NotNull(message = "userId is mandatory")
    private String userId;

    @NotNull(message = "userName is mandatory")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*", message = "userName should not contain special characters")
    private String userName;

    @NotNull(message = "address is mandatory")
    private String address;
    
    
    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setgetUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName.trim();
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

my GlobalExceptionHandler class is

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    // error handle for @Valid
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
            HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        Map<String, Object> body = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        body.put("status", "failure");
        body.put("userId", ""); // here i want the same userId which i got in my request packet
        List<String> errorDetails = ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors().stream()
                .map(x -> x.getDefaultMessage()).collect(Collectors.toList()); //Get all errors
        body.put("errorList", errorDetails);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(body, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I want the same userId which i got in my request packet in my handleMethodArgumentNotValid method. Because I have to pass the same userId in response entity.